# Are there negative effects of freezing clarified stock?

Tags: freezing, food-preservation, stock, chicken-stock, presentation

I have clarified some chicken stock using the ice filtration method. Are there any negative effects to re-freezing this newly clarified stock (such as becoming cloudy again, losing flavor, etc.)?